# change "contents" field to stored,tokenized,indexed for highlight

Tags: lucene, pdfbox

This is how I get details from a `LucenePDFDocument`:

```java
doc = LucenePDFDocument.getDocument(file);
System.out.println("field list: \n" + doc.getFields());
```

And this is the output:

```
field list: 
[<stored<path:D:\Kuliah\rancangan document indexing\dir-pdf\dua.pdf>,
stored<url:D:/Kuliah/rancangan document indexing/dir-pdf/dua.pdf>,
stored,indexed,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS<modified:20170307220729>,
indexed,tokenized<uid:D Kuliah rancangan document indexing dir-pdf dua.pdf 20170307220729>, 
indexed,tokenized<contents:java.io.StringReader@4206a205>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<Author:Acer-2577>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<CreationDate:20150222074338>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<Creator:PDF24 Creator>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<ModificationDate:20150222074338>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<Producer:GPL Ghostscript 9.10>,
stored,indexed,tokenized<Title:Microsoft Word - Vol 10.1 bag ke 2a fix.doc>,
stored<summary:Jurnal Teknologi Informasi, Volume 10 Nomor 1, April ...>]
```

I want to highlight the retrieved word in the "contents" field. Highlight wants a stored field for that, but the "contents" field is just indexed and tokenized. I get an error like: "contents field is not stored".

What I should do to make the "contents" field stored, tokenized, and indexed?
 Should to edit LucenePDFDocument.java? Which part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the content field is indexed but not stored, which means it will not be returned from search results, but will be searchable, and yes, this won't work with a highlighter.

You would need to modify the LucenePDFDocument class to make that field stored. To do that, just pass a string, instead of a reader, to the addTextField call:

```java
String contents = writer.getBuffer().toString();
addTextField(document, "contents", contents);
```

You should also probably remove the "summary" field, since you won't be needing it if you are storing the full content.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i see that just pass a string will make Field.Store.YES  so I can highlight the match  keyword